# In function _start , 'undefined reference to main' , opencv, panorama stitching

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, undefined-reference, image-stitching

I was trying the sample codes under opencv3.0.0-alpha while I encountered the following error:

```
ps@hp-pavilion:~/cvit/opencv_projects$ make stitch

g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o stitch stitch.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/build/glibc-qbmteM/glibc-2.21/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:114: undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:5: recipe for target 'stitch' failed
make: *** [stitch] Error 1
```

I had simply copy-pasted the stitching.cpp file from opencv/samples/cpp and renamed and placed it as stitch.cpp in my projects folder where I also have my makefile. The makefile looks like :

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`

% : %.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)
```

I compile .cpp files for instance temp.cpp simply by

```
make temp
```

and it works perfectly every time. But with this particular stitching code, the error pops-up each time. Here is the sample code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

bool try_use_gpu = false;
vector<Mat> imgs;
string result_name = "stitch_result.jpg";

void printUsage();
int parseCmdArgs(int argc, char** argv);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int retval = parseCmdArgs(argc, argv);
    if (retval) return -1;

    Mat pano;
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu);
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano);

    if (status != Stitcher::OK)
    {
        cout << "Can't stitch images, error code = " << int(status) << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    imwrite(result_name, pano);
    return 0;
}


void printUsage()
{
    cout <<
        "Rotation model images stitcher.\n\n"
        "stitching img1 img2 [...imgN]\n\n"
        "Flags:\n"
        "  --try_use_gpu (yes|no)\n"
        "      Try to use GPU. The default value is 'no'. All default values\n"
        "      are for CPU mode.\n"
        "  --output <result_img>\n"
        "      The default is 'result.jpg'.\n";
}


int parseCmdArgs(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printUsage();
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        if (string(argv[i]) == "--help" || string(argv[i]) == "/?")
        {
            printUsage();
            return -1;
        }
        else if (string(argv[i]) == "--try_use_gpu")
        {
            if (string(argv[i + 1]) == "no")
                try_use_gpu = false;
            else if (string(argv[i + 1]) == "yes")
                try_use_gpu = true;
            else
            {
                cout << "Bad --try_use_gpu flag value\n";
                return -1;
            }
            i++;
        }
        else if (string(argv[i]) == "--output")
        {
            result_name = argv[i + 1];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            Mat img = imread(argv[i]);
            if (img.empty())
            {
                cout << "Can't read image '" << argv[i] << "'\n";
                return -1;
            }
            imgs.push_back(img);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit : I just tried running the sample code from the samples folder itself and it works. The makefile runs perfectly without any error if I place it in the opencv/samples/cpp folder , but doesn't when I copy - paste it to another location.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that the linker can't find your `main` function.  Even though `stitch.cpp` defines `main` (I assume), the linker can't find it.   The reason is unclear, because of the way you constructed your Makefile.  I would make these changes:

- use CXXFLAGS and/or CPPFLAGS for C++, because CFLAGS is for C.
- expand the pkg-config output in make, so you can see what your compiler is being asked to do.

Your Makefile would then look like this:

```
 CXXFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags opencv)
 LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv)

 % : %.cpp
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

I would like to think that with these changes the actual source of the problem will become apparent.